# Geolocation query using referenced entity field with Spring Data and MongoDb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

There are two entities in my application. A user has a location field, and there can be many items (from another collection) referencing him.

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    private GeoJsonPoint location;

    ...

}
```

Item entity with lazy DBRef:

```
@Document(collection = "items")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private User user;

    ...

}
```

I need to query all items from users that are near a point:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, Long> {

    List<Item> findByUserLocationNear(Point point, Distance distance);

    ...

}
```

But that does not work. An exception is thrown because the location field is not an id:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Invalid path reference user.location! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.getPath(QueryMapper.java:853) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:729) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:706) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.createPropertyField(QueryMapper.java:216) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:122) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Did you found the solution??